# Struggling With Unusual Page Layout

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I started working on an interesting page layout idea recently, but I've hit a small(?) issue that I can't seem to find a solution to...

**What I want** is the following:

- Wide screens must see a two-column `[body]` + `[sidebar]` layout.

  - The `body` element will be a wide column on the left.
  - The `sidebar` will appear as a single narrow column on the right, but is actually made up of two stacked divs.
- Narrow screens must see a single column layout, spanning full-width as happens with Bootstrap.

  - First block must be `sidebar-top`
  - Second block must be `body`
  - Third block must be `sidebar-bottom`

Essentially the sidebar must "split" around the content when the screen size gets too narrow.

**What I've got** is almost there.. However, when the height of `#root_body` is less than that of `#root_top_sidebar`, then on a wide page the `#root_bottom_sidebar` segment shifts to directly beneath the body, instead of staying as part of the sidebar.

I can sort of get around this by adding either `margin-bottom` or a decent `min-height` to the body content for wider screens, however this feels rather hacky.. I'm sure there must be a better way to achieve this.

I've tried a few different ideas for this, but the following points are making life difficult:

- Floating both sidebar segments to either the left or the right makes no difference to bottom sidebar segment position.
- Positioning them absolutely is not viable as any of the three containers will hold an unknown amount of data and may change height dynamically while visible.

**Relevant Code**

Trimmed HTML, with classes and IDs left intact:

```
<div class="row">

    <div id="root_top_sidebar" class="col-sm-5 col-md-4">
        <!-- content -->
    </div><!-- .root_top_sidebar -->

    <div id="root_body" class="col-sm-7 col-md-8 accordion-group">
        <!-- content -->
    </div><!-- #root_body -->

    <div id="root_bottom_sidebar" class="col-sm-5 col-md-4">
        <!-- content -->
    </div><!-- .root_bottom_sidebar -->

</div>
```

Related CSS:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    #root_top_sidebar {
        float: right;
    }
}
```

The full project source [can be seen here](https://github.com/ZaLiTHkA/VertigoTheme), with the relevant files located inside the `app/styles/` and `app/views/` folders.

Any HTML/CSS ninjas feel like sharing some wisdom here?

Comment: When the sidebars shift, do you want them to become horizontal?

Comment: Is this the type of functionality you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/mSLS9/

Comment: @TimSPQR, I included sample code. If that's not quite clear, here's a working example of my current situation: http://jsbin.com/INEHAviq/1

Comment: Ok, I understand your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw this again while cleaning up a few almost abandoned projects, and suddenly realised how stupid I was being. Naturally, if I want something to stay the full height of one side of my screen, I must tell it to do that.

Keeping in mind this is not a generic solution, adding `.content` to the `#root_body`'s container and using the follow CSS did the trick in my case, without breaking anything else:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

    html, body,
    .container,
    .row.content {
        min-height: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    #root_body {
        min-height: 100%;
    }

}
```

I'll most likely tweak class assignments at some point, but the basic idea still stands.